# $\int_0^\infty 2xe^{-2x} \: dx=Γ(2)2(1/2)^2$ how to find this result of the integral?

Tags: probability, random-variables

$$\int_0^\infty 2xe^{-2x} \: dx=Γ(2)2(1/2)^2$$

I don't understand. How can we write this? Please can you explain this clearly?

Comment: Is there a reason you write the constant as $2(1/2)^2$ instead of $1/2$?

Comment: Actually, I think writing it like that is helpful given the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Start with the definition of the Gamma function
$$\Gamma(n) = \int_0^{\infty}  \: t^{n-1} e^{-t} dt$$
Substitute $t=2x$ in the definition
$$= \int_0^{\infty}  \: (2x)^{n-1} e^{-2x}\: 2dx$$
To match the power of $x$, set $n=2$.
$$ \Gamma(2)= \int_0^{\infty}  \: 2x e^{-2x} \: 2dx$$
Divide both sides by 2.

Comment: please also note that $\Gamma(n) = (n-1)!$ for positive integers

Answer (score 1):

$$\int_0^{\infty} dx \: x^n \exp{(-\alpha x)} = \frac{\Gamma(n+1)}{\alpha^{n+1}} $$

You should be able to see your result immediately.  The integral may be derived through integration by parts.

Comment: Yes! Thank you:)

Answer (score 0):

Make the substitution $u=2x$ and look up the definition of the Gamma function.